# I wanted to use Smart Pointers, but not sure where to use and when to use

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, stack, smart-pointers

The stack class will maintain a dynamically allocated internal buffer of type unsigned long* which will be created in the constructor and is used to store the elements. This internal buffer must be wrapped in a smart pointer. The buffer is always increased or decreased in blocks and not with each element that comes in or goes out. The increment/decrement block size is passed as a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: If you're manually managing dynamic memory, you  should really be using `new` rather than `malloc`.

Comment: Unrelated: What you call _count_ is usually called _size_ and what you call _size_ is usually called _capacity_.

Comment: just to clarify - they mean smart pointer (like `std::unique_ptr`) not `std::vector`? Because `std::vector` is what most c++ devs would use for m_ulStack

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can use new here?

Comment: Your stack can either hold integers or strings it seems. Why? Do you know what templates are?

Comment: @pm100 I need to use smart pointers like unique_ptr, shared_ptr...not a vector.

Comment: I'm new to c++, I don't know much about templates. This is the basic question given for me.

Comment: How are you proposing to store strings in your stack when your basic data type is `long`?

Comment: I'm converting the data type string to long and storing it in stack

Comment: @Toughcookie You can't treat types the way you do and have defined behavior. Forget about being able to store different types in the stack for now. Design the stack to handle _one_ type. Then replacing it with a template parameter is usually not hard. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/1eGM7eMM9)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn how to use smart pointers then forget this code for a moment. Start a new small program that just makes sure you understand how they work.

- Define a test class with just a string and an int in it. Make them public
- Add a constructor so you can see when its created.
- Add a Destructor so you can see when its deleted.

Create an instance using `std::make_unique`

Set things in the instance, write a function that accepts the unique_ptr as an argument and cout the fields in the test object

repeat with `std::shared_ptr`

Make sure you understand what is going on, dont just try to blindly nail stuff into your stack implementation. If you get stuck post a new question just on this.

The code above has so many other errors in it you will not get a clean set of answers to your specific 'smart pointers' question. Plus you wont be able to make it work reliably

Comment: @Toughcookie NOTE, you should being using std::vector for that buffer though, its an ultra smart pointer to a dynamic array. Still gotta learn to use smart pointers tho